# if you throw 3, 6 sided dice, how many times would add up to 3? The answer is one permutation? how would you set up a function to solve this?

Tags: python-3.x, function, range, permutation, dice

```
def permutations(numberof_sides,sum_of_dice)
    for i in range(numberof_sides):
         for j in range(sum_of_dice):
             x= ???
```

Am I on the right track here?

Comment: Your question is not clear - how many times it will `throw` these 3 dices? It's more a probility question.

Comment: It's not clear what you want your program to do.  Print out a list of all the possibilities, including the sum?  Calculate all the possibilities and then print how many match the target sum?  Run a Monte Carlo simulation and print what percentage of rolls add up to 3?  Needs more info.

Comment: oh, I am sorry.  For example, if I rolled three dice with six sides, what is the minimum number of times I could roll the three dice and the sides add up to 3? The answer would one time, because if I rolled 3 dice and I got all ones, that would add up to 3. Trying to create a function that would show that. The function would need the number of sides of the dice, and the sum of the sides

Comment: this is a question that is better answer by a mathematician, as this is a probabilistic question, but to partially answer it, so long as your target sum S is  `N<=S<= N*max_roll` where N is the number of dice you roll at once, the minimum number of times you need to roll those N dices to get S is one, but with probability C/T, where C=number of way to get the target sum with N dice and T=number of all possible combinations.

Comment: So for example for 6 sided dice and S=3, then C=1 (the only way to sum up to 3 is rolling 1 in all dices) and T=`6**3=216` so you can get your desire result on your first try with probability 1/216

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this answers your question, but we can use `itertools.permutations` to create the list of permutations, then loop through them to see if they sum up properly

A basic example might look like this:

```
from itertools import permutations

# creates repeats of lists, to communicate
# that we have a certain number of dice
def num_list(sides, count):
    modified_list = []
    for i in range(count):
        #appends the same list as many times as is called for
        modified_list += list(range(1, sides + 1))
    return modified_list

# returns sum of elements in list
def sum(list):
    running_sum = 0
    for element in list:
        running_sum += element
    return running_sum

def permutations_basic(num_of_dice, dice_sides, desired_sum):

    # creates a set, to prevent repeats of identical permutations
    output = set()

    # itertools.permutations does most of the heavy lifting here, so
    # we only need to loop through the permutations it generates
    for perm in list(permutations(num_list(dice_sides, num_of_dice), num_of_dice)):

        if sum(perm) == desired_sum:
            output.add(perm)

    return output


# all permutations for 3 D6, that add to 7
for item in permutations_basic(3, 6, 7):
    print(item)
```

Edit: fixed typo in comment

Comment: no need to implement sum, is already provided by python